# Ad-Hoc network as Home in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, ad-hoc-network

i have created an ad-hoc network in Windows 7 Home Premium to play some multiplayer games, but windows won't allow for connections because it's set to Public network, and i can't change it in Network and Sharing Center. Is there any way to set it to Home network OR remove the public network limitations? ( Ps. Firewall is already turned off )

Answer (score 0):

Why use an Ad-Hoc network when you can have a standard windows workgroup LAN?     By Ad-Hoc, I am assuming you mean WiFi Ad-Hoc?

Here is a link that explains how to change/delete network locations in Windows 7

[How do I edit Network Locations in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/236039/how-do-i-edit-network-locations-in-windows-7)

My personal suggestion is always choose Work as the network type.   Both public and private modes disable most network related functions that any regular user would want to do.

Comment: I need to use Ad-Hoc because it's a kinda public Wi-Fi, so some person  i don't know already created a workgroup.