# Windows 10 & Windows 7 PCs can't manange to see my network

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, dd-wrt

Built up my new PC few days ago. And it runs on Windows 10. My old one is on Windows 7.

I used my old *DIR-320* with `dd-wrt` as wireless adapter for Windows 7 one, and the internet is fine.

Network sharing and stuff (Network discovery) is on in every possible groups in both machines.

Also, my Win10 PC use wi-fi adapter (PCI) as well.

And, interesting thing - Windows 10 PC able to see all network map, **except for `dd-wrt` router and Win7 PC** (but I can see there my phone, primary router, smart tv) but Win7 PC sees only my router in network.

I also tried create `HomeGroup` from both PCs sides but I got on `Join` option there.

Why could it be like that?

*P.S.*

Both PCs and `dd-wrt` router got all their network confs automatically (I mean, ip's and stuff)

---

**UPD:**
I remember that `dd-wrt` firewall is on, could it be the case? Or it suppose to be visible at least?

---

**UPD 01.06.2017:**

I turned off `dd-wrt` client router firewall.

I checked both PCs `net view` - in the output there were only their own PCs names.

But when I was checking **Devices & Printers** I saw on both PCs my TV and my phone in list.

Any assumptions?

Comment: Did you try to use the commandline as administrator and using "net view" ?

Comment: @GiaRui in cmd nope, but is it could be different what I see in Network in explorer?

Comment: Or try to see in "start" - "devices and printers", perhaps this thread could help: https://superuser.com/questions/236039/how-do-i-edit-network-locations-in-windows-7

Comment: @GiaRui thx, will do! And update question from home

Comment: @GiaRui asked my mom to check, lol, so  in Win7 `net view` see only PC itself (outputs like `//NAMEOFPC`) and in devices I can see my Smart TV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `dd-wrt` router settings - it was working in `client mode`. Changed it on `client-bridge` and everything became fine.

Looks like just `client mode` not allowes router to be discovered