# How to change network names in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

For various reasons I swapped out our home wireless router for another. It has the same SSID (and WPA version, etc.) setup. But, Windows still detects that it's a different router and assigns the network a different name.

The first name was: `Whiskey Tango Foxtrot+`

The second name is now: `Whiskey Tango Foxtrot+  2` (two spaces)

It appears in the wireless network management snap-in using the SSID (so no problem):
[image]

But, elsewhere it shows the 'wrong' one.

[image]

The number 2 and the spaces (there are two for some reason) bother me. Is there an official way to modify these values? Because I can only find a references to the value in the registry, and I'm not sure how adjusting these will affect my system. But, if there's nowhere else to change it, I'll risk it. The registry values I found are below:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged\`

[image]

`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad\{GUID}`

[image]

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\HomeGroup\NetworkLocations\Home`

[image]

Comment: First of all, I would not recommend messing with the registry at all, you could shoot yourself in the foot.  Did you modify the existing profile under "manage wireless networks"?  If so, you may want to delete the profile entirely and create a new one with the new SSID.  That's the cleanest way to achieve your goal.

Comment: If you look at the first registry pic, it includes a DefaultGatewayMac.  That's looks like the MAC address of the router, which is different from the old router, so the computer thinks it's a completely separate network, as it should for security reasons.  As @pythonian said, deleting both network connections and starting over is the least problematic way.

Comment: @computercarguy Yes, I removed both networks from the `Manage Wireless Networks` window, but that did not work. When I added the new one again, it appeared with the same postfix.

Comment: @pythonian Deleting/Modifying the wireless network profile from the `Manage Wireless Networks` has no effect. I tried that before, it just clears the saved password, but the 'network' still gets a new name.

Comment: @Nick - Well... This is a toughy - I'm wondering if the double space in the SSID has confused Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found the GUI way to do this. In the **Network and Sharing Center**, click on the network icon under **View your active networks** (not the one at the top, that browses your network):

[image]

Now you can change the name! You can also manage, merge and delete other **Network Locations**, which is the correct term.

[image]

Problem solved, all is well in the Universe.

[image]

Answer derived from here: https://superuser.com/a/236482/83776